# Google Maps Javascript API is not loading unless I refresh with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, routes

I have written a Google Map but with the single page structure of Angular, because my page does not actually load the new page, it just injects it.

The Google Map will not be loaded unless I manually refresh the page. How can I do this without the user who probably doesn't know anything about this, not having to refresh the page? I have tried a lot, most specifically `route.reload` and `window.reload`.

This is the actual div that will be injected into the index page which is just a navbar and a middle section where I will inject the map. The problem, is since the map is attached to ui-view of the index page, it doesn't load unless you manually reload it.

```
<div ng-controller="mapController" class="" style="color: rgb(101, 0, 0); background-color: white; color: rgb(101, 0, 0);">
  <div class="" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex: 2; border:1px solid rgb(101, 0, 0);">
    <div class="amenity-title" style="flex: 1; margin: 1em">
      <p><span style="font-size: 28px; font-family: crimson text, sans-serif;letter-spacing: 1.2;">NEIGHBORHOOD</span></p>
      <p style="font-family: sans-serif;">Part of Chicago's Near North Side community area, it is roughly bounded by North Avenue, Lake Shore Drive, Oak Street, and Clark Street.
      </p>
      <a ui-sref="imagesOfApartments"><h3 style="color: rgb(101, 0, 0); font-family: sans-serif;">view apartments</h3></a>
      <a ui-sref="amenities"><h3 style="color: rgb(101, 0, 0); font-family: sans-serif;">view ammenities</h3></a>
      <p ng-click="goBack()"><a href="#" style="color: rgb(101, 0, 0);font-family: Crimson-text, sans-serif;">back</a></p>
    </div>
    <div style="font-family: sans-serif; height:450px; display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex: 2;">
      <div id="" style="flex-direction: column; display: flex; flex: 1; height: 450px; width: 50%;background-color: white; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">    
        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; margin: 1em; height: 50px; width: 150px;background-color: white; border: 1px solid rgb(101, 0, 0);">
          <h3>All Locations</h3>
        </div>
        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; margin: 1em; height: 50px; width: 150px;background-color: white; border: 1px solid rgb(101, 0, 0);">
          <h3>Restaurants</h3>
        </div>
        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; margin: 1em; height: 50px; width: 150px;background-color: white; border: 1px solid rgb(101, 0, 0);">
          <h3>Attractions</h3>
        </div>
        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; margin: 1em; height: 50px; width: 150px;background-color: white; border: 1px solid rgb(101, 0, 0);">
          <h3>Hotels</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="" style="display: flex; flex: 2; height: 450px; width: 50%;background-color: white;">
        <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height:430px; margin: 5px; background-color: rgb(101, 0, 0);">map</div>
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div><!-- end of apartment details container-->
```

I call the map here; this works fine.

```
function initMap() {
    let options = {
        zoom:8,
        center: {lat:81.9057, lng:-87.6303}
    }

    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);

    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat:81.9057, lng:-87.6303},
        map:map,
        icon:'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'
    });

    let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content:'<h5>address</h5>'
    });

    marker.addListener('click', function(){
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

I thought if I added a controller I would just call route reload and every time the page with the controller loaded it would run the controller which would run the `route.reload` function, but it is not working. Can anyone see why?

```
app.controller("mapController", ['$route', function ($http,$scope,$route) {  
    $route.reload();
    console.log('route');
    }  
}]);
```

I attached the added mapController (I added the map controller to the index page where my main template is, that doesn't change).

Comment: Try place the `initMap()` call in a `$timeout`, it probably fails because of beeing executed prematurely.

Comment: Hi David not sure what that means but I  think the issue is I have a static sidebar and navbar that never loads.  So it doesn't load the map because it just inserts it.  It seems if there was a way to simply reload the page it would fix the issue or anything that would stop a user from having to manually refresh.  I thought that was what the page reload was for.  I am now seeing why angular lost out in the race between react and everything else..